# IGNORABLE_404_URLS not working

Tags: django, http-status-code-404

I'm getting lots of 404 errors as a result of scripts. I'm trying to block many of them from sending emails as they are random bots. I have the following in my `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

import re
IGNORABLE_404_URLS = (
    re.compile(r'\.(php|cgi|do|action|asmx|asp)$'),
    re.compile(r'^/phpmyadmin/'),
    re.compile(r'^/mysql-admin/'),
)
```

I followed the instructions as per this page:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/

How come i'm still getting emials when I do `https://www.mysite.com/index.do`? isn't the `.do` covered in the first line of the reg ex? I'm using django 1.6.

How do I get django to stop sending me emails when not needed? My regular expression was taken off of their documentation website!

**EDIT**

I also tried `re.compile(r'^\.(php|cgi|do|action|asmx|asp)/$'),` and it's not working. What would the regex be with `APPEND_SLASH`.

Comment: What is the full request url, is it appending a ```/``` or is there a query string at the end? The regex is applied to the full request path, so if there is, then your first regex wouldn't match. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-IGNORABLE_404_URLS

Comment: I also put this just now: `re.compile(r'^\.(php|cgi|do|action|asmx|asp)/$'),` and its not working. What would the regex be with the `/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely because the setting `APPEND_SLASH` is enabled. This will append a slash to the URL if it doesn't match any of your other ones. Since you're testing 404's, we know that it won't exist.

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-APPEND_SLASH)

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a logging problem, not part of the IGNORABLE_404 setup. I had the following in settings:

`LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'include_html': True
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        }
    }
}`

When I changed `'level': 'WARNING'` to `'level': 'ERROR'`, it worked fine.